# Bake actions to use child of constraint

Tags: constraints, gltf

I am a game developer and I am very new to Blender.

I have made a human and gun model in blender. The gun's main bone has a child of bone constraint targeted to humans hand. I have made an animation where the human walks slowly with the gun and another where he runs quickly.

The animations work fine at first but once i export to gltf it doesn't work. The gun stays still as if the child of constraint doesn't exist. So after some searching i was told to bake the actions.

I baked one and it worked just fine, so I baked the other one and started to see problems. The second one works fine but now the first one is exactly like the second one as if the second one overwrote the first. I tried to bake the second then the first and then the first overwrote the second.

After some testing i noticed that all baked actions for the gun take the action that was last active in human NLA.so if the run animation was active in NLA all baked actions for the gun are run animation.

Side note the animations where the same with difference of amount of keyframes meaning the walk action was 20 frames while the run was 30 so when the run overwrote the walk the walk action was still 20 keyframes.

What do I do?

Comment: Push the current action down, assign some other action, bake; repeat.  Since you probably want to be baking with clear constraints, baking different actions onto different armatures makes sense; use dope sheet/action editor to assign actions to final copy when done baking.